# Cannot find number of lines in a file using Scanner

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to calculate the number of lines in a file using a Scanner in the below code but for some reason I am stuck in an infinite loop.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class FileCount{
    File fileCount;
    public FileCount(String name_of_file){
        fileCount = new File(name_of_file);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileCount f = new FileCount("test.txt");
        System.out.println(f.num_of_records());
    }
    public int num_of_records() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner handler = new Scanner(this.fileCount);
        int num_of_lines = 0;
        for(int i=0; handler.hasNextLine(); i++){
            num_of_lines = i;
        }
        handler.close();
        return num_of_lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need a `Scanner` for this, just use a `BufferedReader` and do `.readLine()`.

Comment: but why am i stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: got it sorry for such a stupid quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check that it has a next line, but then you never tell it to do anything with that line. Something like this should work.

```
for(int i=0; handler.hasNextLine(); i++){
        handler.nextLine();
        num_of_lines = i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `Scanner`, you may consider using `BufferedReader` instead:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your_file_name"));
int num_of_lines;
for (num_of_lines=0; reader.readLine()!=null; num_of_lines++) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Scanner or a BufferedReader either. You can do it in about three lines with a LineNumberReader. First seek to the file size, then get the current line number.